# SP2010 - How to set URL for GetRatingOnUrl method?

Tags: 2010, spservices, rating

I'm trying to get the ratings for a list item in a custom list, using the GetRatingOnUrl method. List is rating enabled. I'm accessing this method via the SPServices jquery library. I'm not sure how to set the URL parameter. Currently I'm setting the url this way:
/*subsitename*/*subsitename*/*subsitename*/*subsitename*/*listname*/*id_*.000
since this is how the item was appearing in the FieldRef. I tried setting the URL without the '_.000' too.
I get this error:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error probably occurs due not sufficient permissions for a user in User Profile service application.

How to configure permissions of User Profile service application:

- Go to `Central Administration` -> `Manage service applications`
- Select `User Profile service` and click `Permissions` button in Ribbon UI
- Specify the accounts that have access to invoke this service application

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, according to the MSDN docs, a SQL Exception is thrown if "The user does not have permission to view the social ratings for url." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.getratingonurl.aspx